# Cannot implicitly convert SuggestionComment to ICollection<SuggestionComment>

Tags: entity-framework

I know exactly what the error says; however, I am not sure how to get the functionality I want from my code.

```
 var item = from l in context.Suggestions
                       join a in context.SuggestionVotes on l.id equals a.SuggestionId
                       join b in context.SuggestionComments on l.id equals b.SuggestionId
                       join c in context.Users on b.UserId equals c.id
                       where l.id == id
                       select new Suggestion
                       {
                           id = l.id,
                           Title = l.Title,
                           Description = l.Description,
                           PosterId = l.PosterId,
                           SuggestionComments = b
                       };
```

I'm trying to set `SuggestionComments(ICollection<SuggestionComment>)` equal to all records in my table `SuggestionComments` that belong to my original Suggestion object.

**Suggestion**

```
int id (PK)
string Title
string Description
```

**SuggestionComment**

```
int id (PK)
int SuggestionId (FK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your direct problem is that `b` is a `SuggestionComment` instance, not a collection of `SuggenstionComment`s and you're attempting to set it to the `SuggestionComments` nav collection property of a `Suggestion` object.

But your real issue is that you're using joins - why aren't you using navigation properties? For example:

```
context.Suggestions
    .Where( s => s.Id == id )
    .Select( s => new Suggestion
    {
        id = s.id,
        Title = s.Title,
        Description = s.Description,
        PosterId = s.PosterId,
        SuggestionComments = s.SuggestionComments
    } );
```

Update after comment that clarified situation:

```
var suggestion = context.Suggestions
    .Where( s => s.Id == id )
    .Select( s => new
    {
        Suggestion = s,
        Comments = s.SuggestionComments,
        CommentUsers = s.SuggestionComments.Select( sc => sc.User )
    }
    .Single()
    .Select( at => at.Suggestion )
    .Single();

 // if tracking is enabled in your DbContext, the suggestion object
 //  will have its SuggestionComments collection loaded
 //  as well as each SuggestionComment's User property
```

Comment: Hm, this looks interesting, I was unaware that I could do that. Usually I do .Include or use joins but for this instance .Include was not workin since My suggestionComments themselves hold User objects. Anyway, I tried your suggesstion and I got `The entity or complex type 'jdmexchangeModel.Suggestion' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do as you're simply copying the values of a `Suggestion` into a new instance of `Suggestion` - why can't you simply select the original `Suggestion`?  If you really want to do that, project the results to an anonymous class, enumerate, and construct the new `Suggestion` object

Comment: What I am basically trying to do is something like this. `Suggestion s = context.Suggestions.Include(P => P.SuggestionComments.Include(P => P.User)).Single()` which doesn't seem to be possible. That is why I was trying to use joins to manually set all the properties myself. My SuggestionComment has an `(FK)` to my Users table `(PK) id`. Does that sort of make sense?

Comment: project what you want to eager load into an anonymous class, enumerate, then you're good to go.  I'll update the solution

Comment: It's not throwing any more errors; however, it seems to not be selecting the associated user objects. I'm going to mess with it some more and see if I cant get it working.

Comment: try `.ToArray()` after `Select( sc => sc.User )`